# How to overwrite arguments of a function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on a Next.js app and this type exist to to defined `getStaticProps` methods in pages:

```
export type GetStaticProps<
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
> = (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext<Q, D>
) => Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<P>> | GetStaticPropsResult<P>
```

The problem is that `GetStaticPropsContext` is defined as follows and is not generic:

```
export type GetStaticPropsContext<
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
> = {
  params?: Q
  preview?: boolean
  previewData?: D
  locale?: string
  locales?: string[]
  defaultLocale?: string
}
```

In my app, `locale`, `locales` and `defaultLocale` are never `undefined`

Is there a way to overwrite `GetStaticPropsContext` on `GetStaticProps` without completely copy/pasting `GetStaticProps` to a new type and changing `GetStaticPropsContext` with another type?

I'm just worried about maintainability if I have to copy everything and was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Yes sorry I knew this was confusing, we cannot overwrite either `GetStaticPropsContext` or its properties using generics (as far as I know how TypeScript work) - which is why I was asking this question

Comment: Yes, this type is optional and is used to make it to define a function like this `const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = (context) => {`  but technically you could define it like this `function getStaticProps(context: GetStaticPropsContext): GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>` - I would prefer the to use a function type as it is less code, but I also dont want to copy/paste the type

Comment: I've finally finished fixing the links in my answer, sorry I didn't check them (and the explanation) better before posting.

Comment: Wow amazing answer.. thanks - I learned a lot :)

Comment: Hey I just noticed a potential problem with your solution, I'm getting a `Type 'MyGetStaticProps' is not generic.` when trying to use with a generic `GetStaticProps<someType>`. Is there a way to fix this without copy/pasting the generic statement? Playground: shorturl.at/ckLSU

Comment: Sorry, I meant to close the loop on the generics. (That playground link doesn't work. You can use https://tsplay.dev to shorten playground links. It's safer because it can *only* shorten playground links, so SO doesn't forbid actual links to it in comments.) I don't 100% need your example, but it would help to be sure I get a solution that applies to what you're trying to do. Sadly, I think we'll have to copy those generic definitions. :-( But I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I added all the "real types" and also the failing case (commented out) at the bottom: https://tsplay.dev/N9P6qw - really curious if there is a solution, otherwise it might be good to add a clarification in your answer

Comment: Thanks for that playground! Good news: We don't have to duplicate those type parameter definitions, we can use our `UpdateContext` directly, so the generics pass through it. I've updated the answer, but here's the final link: https://tsplay.dev/mM1a6m (That said, I've done a *lot* of editing on the answer across the course of all this and I've definitely made editing mistakes [I know because I've caught some of them later]. Would you do me a favor and just double-check that I haven't missed any? TIA!)

Comment: It looks good thank you! So I guess there is no way not to use the extra "wrapper" without copying the generics? It does make the syntax a lot more tricky to use/understand for most developers so I was just curious. Initially, I was looking for a single "drop-in" replacement for `GetStaticProps`

Comment: Well, `UpdateContext<GetStaticProps<MyProps>>` isn't *that* complicated. :-) As far as I can tell, you can't infer type parameter definitions, so you'd have to copy them: https://tsplay.dev/w61EyW That changes the usage to `MyGetStaticProps<MyProps>`. Simpler, granted, but not markedly. So if not copying is a big deal, I'd stick with using `UpdateContext` directly. But copying probably that big a deal; you'll probably (but only probably) get a type error if `GetStaticProps`'s type parameters change in a future version, which makes it pretty easy to fix by copying the updated definitions.

Comment: Yes exactly, but the challenge is I might not be aware of those types are updated, hence it would create potentially fragile code?

Comment: That's what I meant about you'd *probably* get an error if the type parameters changed, but it's only a "probably." You definitely would if the new ones were incompatible with the ones you copied to start with, but subtle changes may not get flagged up (but then, that also many not be a big deal). Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a new type that you can use to create your function, we have these steps:

1. Derive a new `GetStaticPropsContext` type that doesn't allow `locale`, `locales`, or `defaultLocale` to be missing or `undefined`.
2. Create a generic type that we can use to derive a new `GetStaticProps` type that uses our new context type.
3. Use the new generic type from #2 where we would have used `GetStaticProps`.

Parts 1 and 2 are reusable, and part 3 (using it) is just using the new type on the function.

Note that this is written for maximum flexibility and minimum assumptions, because you said you wanted to avoid copy and paste on the existing types. It's possible to make it a bit less verbose by making more assumptions. That said, the actual code isn't that long (see the end), it just takes a fair bit of explanation.

### 1. Derive a new `GetStaticPropsContext` type

You can make a stricter version of `Required` that also removes `undefined` from the properties of an object type:

```typescript
type RequiredNotUndefined<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[Key], undefined>;
};
```

That uses a mapped type with a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to remove the optionality, and the [`Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) to remove `undefined` from its type.

Then, since we only want to apply this to some of the properties in `GetStaticPropsContext`, we can use this type to split off just those properties to pass through the above:

```typescript
type SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<T, Keys extends keyof T> =
    RequiredNotUndefined<Pick<T, Keys>> & Omit<T, Keys>;
```

We use [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) to apply `RequiredNotUndefined` only to the named properties in `Keys`, and then intersect those with the other properties (via [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)).

Then you could create your own context type that derives from `GetStaticPropsContext`, making the three properties you care about required and not `undefined`:

```typescript
export type MyStaticContext = SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<
    GetStaticPropsContext,
    "locale" | "locales" | "defaultLocale"
>;
```

So, that's the context part so far; here's an example of it working: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEF5PUAUCcCmATBAzAlgO2aALgTwAcEBnAKDK1wTlQEMBjBUAEXQdwB4AVAPlADeZUCNABtANYJ8ALlAlccLAHMAunO6gAPqACumFBmxIA3GQC+lTNVqNmMOnBLIAqnAA2ARV018oBAAe1AYkrOxcCkqYytryiipiqvwCloGEAPZwuHhE9ogAbugIAO4sdLh0EHFRMTr07s6x6QBGAFYIHLH6hljIFGmZ2QTEoADiCLgAyhW47PDphCQAwunWgVzCop7+QQghsI7OSG5ePnB+0A5Orh7evgA0myIsO8FIofAIhSVlFVWf31K5ToZH40CEolAhEcdAAtiQAPxyTxmSGEApFYpI0DNdLpdwIOiYVGidFfTG-OjYlgkkTudIMOgE7GRFS00D0xkExFyVnRRLswx0XTuXAAGQZTIQLPi0TM5jMZAGWRyI3GUxmczgCxInE2MFee3egnEUlk1RU6lARL85iqAlN0l5srUchtoHMjxE23WRo+hxup18-wDx1uZ3wXtYhv2AIpwP+GJ+wNBVQAFJsGKtqEE5OrpuUtTqVmsgpxPPdWLwyABKCD8eaw9DOTj5zUMeaLABKpBFXBgvH4OjbhY72u7vdFnAH-QCGRVw2YI9mY51PZIfenYM2Ogd6J1chgJlABSZ6CQ5WlckwulhzRosVx+MJmA9O5NiCQ6EQHDkPa-P64Mep7uOel7Yjed4PjoT4EkSb4iLuoCYOkuAAGLpN0ciKD4wFfGeF7UBBt73nAj54nBr6WEqc6DKqzD-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) (thank you for providing the Next.js types!!)

### 2. Create a generic type to derive an updated `GetStaticProps`

But we don't really want to do `type MyStaticContext = ___`; we want to update `GetStaticProps`'s `context` parameter type instead.

We can do that by mapping the function type, and using our `SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined` type to modify the type of `context`:

```typescript
type UpdateContext<T> = T extends (context: infer Context extends GetStaticPropsContext) => infer Return
    ? (context: SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<Context, "locale" | "locales" | "defaultLocale">) => Return
    : never;
```

That uses the powerful and underdocumented [`infer` feature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to let us get the context and return types from `GetStaticProps`; then we modify `context`'s type.

We're ready to use it!

### 3. Use the new generic type when using `GetStaticProps`

Suppose your props type is:

```typescript
type MyProps = {
    someField: string
};
```

Then your function would be:

```typescript
export const getStaticProps: UpdateContext<GetStaticProps<MyProps>> = async (context) => {
    return {
        props: {
            someField: 'yes'
        }
    }
};
```

...and within that, `context.locale`, `context.locales`, and `context.defaultLocale` are all non-optional and non-`undefined`.

### All together

Here's that all together ([on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEF5PUAUCcCmATBAzAlgO2aALgTwAcEBnAKDK1wTlQEMBjBUAEXQdwB4AVAPlADeZUCNABtANYJ8ALlAlccLAHMAunO6gAPqACumFBmxIA3GQC+lTNVqNmMOnBLIAqnAA2ARV018oBAAe1AYkrOxcCkqYytryiipiqvwCloGEAPZwuHhE9ogAbugIAO4sdLh0EHFRMTr07s6x6QBGAFYIHLH6hljIFGmZ2QTEoADiCLgAyhW47PDphCQAwunWgVzCop7+QQghsI7OSG5ePnB+0A5Orh7evgA0myIsO8FIofAIhSVlFVWf31K5ToZH40CEolAhEcdAAtiQAPxyTxmSGEApFYpI0DNdLpdwIOiYVGidFfTG-OjYlgkkTudIMOgE7GRFS00D0xkExFyVnRRLswx0XTuXAAGQZTIQLPi0TM5jMZAGWRyI3GUxmczgCxInE2MFee3egnEUlk1RU6lARL85iqAlN0l5srUchtoHMjxE23WRo+hxup18-wDx1uZ3wXtYhv2AIpwP+GJ+wNBVQAFJsGKtqEE5OrpuUtTqVmsgpxPPdWLwyABKCD8eaw9DOTj5zUMeaLABKpBFXBgvH4OjbhY72u7vdFnAH-QCGRVw2YI9mY51PZIfenYM2Ogd6J1chgJlABSZ6CQ5WlckwulhzRosVx+MJmA9O5NiCQ6EQHDkPa-P64Mep7uOel7Yjed4PjoT4EkSb4iLuoCYOkuAAGLpN0ciKD4wFfGeF7UBBt73nAj54nBr6WEqc6DKqzD-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-Ac1zPOQteXw0IqEVQNAc1woQBJ6M4MgUJVACy+CdqE4LKSQ6TJWhRTuEgPnRBYirKtkRMKIVEwFiuvtyGjGNy62iftr7nDe774PQPp+CYAw-NE9jJvdaI5frAAdMrBLKRFHGgAAegiyk10E9ca6QTdgC37ed4L3e66K+tSv3Ldtx3kJd7gtdkoCoARQAgqE8GBE7LujdaULjjQBB4EZBVIOkpCYAA5NkRXZLCvHoBgfSQs3HFD5CiCc9zVct-uixyOxaeohA7B1DuHUAl98CkEvjZEQllRCWAVGQIAA)):

```typescript
// ==== >>>One time<<< declarations that get reused

type RequiredNotUndefined<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[Key], undefined>;
};

type SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<T, Keys extends keyof T> =
    RequiredNotUndefined<Pick<T, Keys>> & Omit<T, Keys>;

type UpdateContext<T> = T extends (context: infer Context extends GetStaticPropsContext) => infer Return
    ? (context: SelectiveRequiredNotUndefined<Context, "locale" | "locales" | "defaultLocale">) => Return
    : never;

// ==== Example use:

type MyProps = {
    someField: string
};

export const getStaticProps: UpdateContext<GetStaticProps<MyProps>> = async (context) => {
    context.locale
    //       ^? (property) locale: string
    context.locales
    //       ^? (property) locales: string[]
    context.defaultLocale
    //       ^? (property) defaultLocale: string
    context.preview // As an example of a property that doesn't get modified
    //       ^? (property) preview?: boolean | undefined
    return {
        props: {
            someField: 'yes'
        }
    }
};
```

...and in there as you can see in the playground (and comments above), the `locale`, `locales`, and `defaultLocale` properties of `context` are non-optional and not `undefined`, but other properties such as `preview` are unchanged.